# How to prevent TextBox flickering?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, flicker, doublebuffered

I try to prevent TextBox flickering with no success so far.
The TextBox is multiline readonly.

This code run a few times per second. The text has about 10k characters.

```
int ss = txt.SelectionStart;
int sl = txt.SelectionLength;
txt.Text = s;
txt.SelectionStart = ss;
txt.SelectionLength = sl;
```

Resarching the problem gives me the following possible solutions
- but none of them worked.

1) LockWindowUpdate

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr hWndLock);

//...

LockWindowUpdate(txt.Handle);
txt.Text = someText;
LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero);
```

2) SetStyle

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
```

3) SuspendLayout / ResumeLayout (guess it has nothing to do with paint - but just a try)

```
txt.SuspendLayout();
txt.Text = s;
txt.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: Why do you have flickering in the first place? Setting the Text property shouldn't cause any flicker. What are you doing and what is the problem?

Comment: The only time I have seen flickering is when you are doing several small updates to the text box.  If that is what you are doing, perhaps you should batch them using a StringBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `CreateParams` of the parent form has to use the [`WS_EX_COMPOSITED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode).Demand();
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

****This is the perfect way .** there is a native Win32 control that supports handling of IP Addresse

```
 public class IPTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public IPTextBox() : base()
        {

        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode).Demand();
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ClassName = "SysIPAddress32";
                return cp;
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this question doesn't imply entering a IP address. That would be a special case. It's all about flickering of a plain text box.